# QGIS randomly omitting polygons

Tags: qgis

I am using QGIS 2.12.3

I have two layers, one a complete grid of 1km squares, the other polygons representing urban land.

Whether I intersect clip or difference these two layers, some of the km squares are omitted from the new layer. It can't be a data issue as the missing squares are different depending on which operation I undertake, although they appear consistent for each operation.

Can anyone explain - I must admit I find the geoprocessing tools can often ignore a polygon on an layer with no obvious reason (yes I have tried validating the layers with no errors).

[image: I have managed to upload an image - the ignored squares are the white one 'peeping' from behind the urban layer]

Note how the same polygon interacts properly with many other squares.

The polygon does fail validation but I have been around the periphery of failed squares and can see no faults.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of the resulting layers with the missing squares?

Comment: if you have Shapefiles you can update the spatial index.

Comment: Could you upload your shapefiles to a public server so that others could test it?

Comment: Had this same problem and I think converting to single-parts and updating my spatial index did the job.

Comment: I prepared a svreenshot - but I can't see how to add it.

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered a similar situation when using QGIS for clipping a polyline layer using a polygon layer.

The problem is the following (as I have understood it): the layer to be clipped has to be singleparts (a attribute table record for each feature) layer. When clipping, the result layer might contain multiple features for one record and I believe that this is causing exclusion of other features. QGIS has 2 functions named "Multipart to singleparts" and "Singleparts to Multipart" under Vector->Geometry Tools section that might be helpful for you.

I hope this helps a bit to find a workaround for this issue.

Regards, 
Ioana

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid that hasn't worked.

I have even created a new grid from scratch, and still the same squares are omitted.

Interestingly, looking closely at one square that doesn't work it is only overlapped by one polygon - at several points, but other squares intersected by it in the same fashion work perfectly.